Terrible bulk insertion performance for SQL Server, ODBC 18
Setup: the SQL Server is in recovery mode "Simple". I also tried disabling all indices, without any noticeable performance increase, so you may consider them being disabled. The server has 2 Cores and 4 GB of RAM. The table is a heap table, without clustered index.
SQL Server info:
Microsoft SQL Server 2022 (RTM-CU14-GDR) (KB5042578) - 16.0.4140.3 (X64) 
Copyright (C) 2022 Microsoft Corporation
Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)

I am having hard time to speed up insertions into the database from the application. I tried multiple ways to "bulk insert":

Method A: call CLR from Python. Basically

import clr

clr.AddReference("System")
import System
# ...
bc = System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy(...)
#... build the datatable
datatable = System.Data.DataTable()
for c in cls.columns():
    datatable .Columns.Add(name, type)
for row in data:
    dotnet_row: System.Data.DataRow = datatable.NewRow()
# ...
    dotnet_row[colname] = rowvalue
    datatable.Rows.Add(dotnet_row)
# ...
bc.DestinationTableName = ...
bc.BatchSize = 10000
bc.WriteToServer.Overloads[System.Data.DataTable](datatable)

This gives me about 2200 rows / second insertion speed, for a sample of 16000 rows.

Method B: use pandas.to_sql(...). More or less same performance as above.

Method C: call ODBC Driver directly from C++, using dense parameter arrays (my data has no NULLs, so it's neatly packed):


    TRYODBC(hEnv, SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQLSetEnvAttr(hEnv, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (SQLPOINTER) SQL_OV_ODBC3_80, 0));
    // ... reading data from the filesystem, establishing connection, etc... 
    TRYRET1(hdbc, SQL_HANDLE_DBC, SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hdbc, &hstmt));
    TRYRET1(hstmt, SQL_HANDLE_STMT, SQLSetStmtAttr(hstmt, SQL_ATTR_USE_BOOKMARKS, SQL_UB_OFF, 0));
    // bind by column 
    TRYRET1(hstmt, SQL_HANDLE_STMT, SQLSetStmtAttr(hstmt, SQL_ATTR_PARAM_BIND_TYPE, SQL_PARAM_BIND_BY_COLUMN, 0));
    // important bit: use parameter arrays
    TRYRET1(hstmt, SQL_HANDLE_STMT, SQLSetStmtAttr(hstmt, SQL_ATTR_PARAMSET_SIZE, (SQLPOINTER)data.nbRows, 0));
    // the insertion statement has a TABLELOCK
    uint32_t offset = 0;
    // starts at 1, the column 0 being the Bookmarks
    for (size_t i = 1; i <= data.headers_sizes.size(); i++)
    {
        int c_type = typemapping[data.types[i - 1]][0];
        int sql_type = typemapping[data.types[i - 1]][1];
        void* begin_array = data.rawData.data() + offset;
        // bind array of values to send to the driver
        TRYRET1(hstmt, SQL_HANDLE_STMT, SQLBindParameter(hstmt, i, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, c_type, sql_type, 0, 0, begin_array, 0, NULL));
        offset += typesizes[data.types[i - 1]] * data.nbRows;
    }
    // finally, execute.
    TRYRET1(hstmt, SQL_HANDLE_STMT, SQLExecute(hstmt));

This method doubles the performance, and gives me about 4800 rows / second for the same sample of 16000 rows.
This is all pretty miserable. Is the real issue the low spec of the machine (2 Cores, 4 GB memory) ? I can't use BCP.

"The server has 1 CPU" do you mean 1 CPU core/thread? Otherwise 1 CPU doesn't mean a lot to us; CPUs have "many* thread and how many they have varies.

Yes, I meant 1 core.

Why?! You've paid for enterprise edition and you have to buy a minimum of 2 two core packs; this means you've paid about $22,500 for licences you aren't using! You're only using about $7,500 of the $30,000 you spent on licences.

Ha interesting. I didn't pay anything, i am just a developer :) But thank you for the insight.

So you're company has paid... The you doesn't mean explicitly you here.

I recommend talking to your administrator and getting that VM to have better resources; SQL Server Enterprise and Windows isn't built for such a poorly resourced host. I would happily blame poor performance on the host here.

Thanks for your input, I will talk about this issue

Option 1 or 3 is probably the fastest, but yeah you need more resources on the VM. Don't set the batch size, that actually slows things down. Use SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock for a bit better perf at the cost of locking the whole table.

@ThomA okey i double checked: actually 2 cores... Not sure if that"s good or bad news

I still stand by my statement. There's still ~$15,000 of licences not being used and that is a painfully underspeced server when you're paying out for Enterprise.

You should use bcp or whatever to get a baseline for how fast it can go, since it's hard to beat for pure speed, and then see how far your solutions are off. I do agree about bumping up the VM specs though, my raspberry pi has more cream than that

Also using 4Gb for a SQL Server VM is very, very low...  The OS will take about 2Gb and SQL Server exe near by 1 Gb... this stay only 1 Gb for your data, meta data, network services, etc... I usually recommend a minimum of 16GB and much more for Enterprise version...
